# Creating a instance using a model shows 'not a function' (node using mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

II make a user model and want to use it in the users.js route file.but it shows me **userModel is not a function**. anyone know what's happening here? Thanks

//my User model in models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var url = 'mongodb://fr:fran98@ds013250.mlab.com:13250/node';
mongoose.connect(url); 

var db = mongoose.connection;


db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {//when connected
        console.log('connected to mongo db');
        //User Schema
        var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
            username: {
                type:String,
                index:true
            },
            email: {
                type:String
            },
            password: {
                type:String,
                required:true,
                bcrypt:true

            },
            profileimage: {
                type:String
            }
        }, { timestamps: 'created_at' } );   

        //add "speak" functionality to our documents:  
        UserSchema.methods.speak = function(){
            var greeting = this.name
                ? "His name is " + this.name
                : "I do not have a nanme";
            console.log(greeting);
        }       

        module.exports = {
            userModel: mongoose.model('User',UserSchema),
            createUser: function(newUser,callback){
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
                    // Store hash in your password DB.
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser.save(callback);

                });

            }
        };               
});
```

//routes/users.js

```
    const User = require('../modules/user');

    var userModel = User.userModel;
    var newUser = new userModel({
        username:username,
        email:email,
        password:password,
        profileimage: profileImageName
    });

    //Create User
    User.createUser(newUser,function(err,user){
        if(err){throw err}
        console.log(user);
    });
```

**ADDS :**
//more about routes/users.js

```
"use strict";
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: '/uploads' });

const User = require('../modules/user');
//this User returns: 1,User = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema)
//2: User.createUser = function(newUser,callback){
        //  newUser.save(callback);
        // }    

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{
      'title': 'Register',
      'errors':[]
  });
});
router.post('/register',upload.single('profileimage'), function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    console.log(username,email,password,password2);
    //check for image field
    if(req.file){
        console.log('uploading file...');

        //file info
        var profileImageOriginalName = req.file.originalname;//the name before uploaded
        var profileImageName = req.file.filename;//name the server give it when it uploaded

        var profileImageMime = req.file.mimetype;
        var profileImagePath = req.file.path;
        var profileImageSize = req.file.size;
    }else{
        //set a default image
        profileImageName = 'noimage.png'; 
    }
    //form validation, using express-validator
req.checkBody({
 'email': {
    notEmpty: true,
    isEmail: {
      errorMessage: 'Invalid Email'
    }
  },
  'password': {
    notEmpty: true,
    isLength: {
      options: [{ min: 4, max:20 }],
      errorMessage: 'Password Must be between 4 and 8 chars long' // Error message for the validator, takes precedent over parameter message
    },
    errorMessage: 'Invalid Password' // Error message for the parameter
  },
  'password2': {
    notEmpty: true,
    matches: {
      options: [password, 'g'] // pass options to the validator with the options property as an array
      // options: [/example/i] // matches also accepts the full expression in the first parameter
    },
    errorMessage: 'Password Not Match' // Error message for the parameter
  },
  'username': { //
    //optional: true, // won't validate if field is empty
    notEmpty: true,
    isLength: {
      options: [{ min: 4, max: 50 }],
      errorMessage: 'Username Must be between 4 and 8 chars long' // Error message for the validator, takes precedent over parameter message
    },    
    errorMessage: 'Invalid Name'
  }
});



    // req.checkBody('username','userName field is required').notEmpty();

    // req.checkBody('email','Email field not valid').isEmail();
    // req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
    // req.checkBody('password2','Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    //check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    //or let errors = req.asyncValidationErrors();
    //errors is like below:
    //[
    //   {param: "email", msg: "required", value: "<received input>"},
    //   {param: "email", msg: "valid email required", value: "<received input>"},
    //   {param: "password", msg: "6 to 20 characters required", value: "<received input>"}
    // ]

    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            'title': 'Register',
            'errors': errors,
            'username':username,
            'email':email,
            'password':password,
            'password2':password2
        });
    }else{
        console.log('pass the validation.');
        var userModel = User.userModel;
        // var newUser = new userModel({
        //     username:username,
        //     email:email,
        //     password:password,
        //     profileimage: profileImageName
        // });

userModel.create({ 
            username:username,
            email:email,
            password:password,
            profileimage: profileImageName
}, function (err, res) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(res);
  // saved!
})


        //Create User
        User.createUser(newUser,function(err,user){
            if(err){throw err}
            console.log(user);
        });//user model
        // newUser.save(function(err,newUser){
        //     if(err){console.log(err);}
        //     console.log(newUser);
        // });

        //success Message
        req.flash('success','you are now registered and may log in');
        //redirect to the home page
        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});




router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login',{
      'title': 'Login'
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can you add other details, like schema definition etc? i tried the above and it works for me.

Comment: of course, I've added it.have a check

Comment: try removing `userModel` declaration in the module export. Instead place `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)` after your done declaring the schema. Then get the model in your controller by doing this `User = mongoose.model('User');`

Comment: Do not quiet understand ,can you put the code above,many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I moved the schema/method/export outside of `db.once` and it works.

```
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function () {//when connected
   console.log('connected to mongo db');
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    index: true
},
email: {
    type: String
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    bcrypt: true

},
profileimage: {
    type: String
}
}, {timestamps: 'created_at'});

//add "speak" functionality to our documents:
UserSchema.methods.speak = function () {
var greeting = this.name
    ? "His name is " + this.name
    : "I do not have a nanme";
console.log(greeting);
};

module.exports = {
userModel: mongoose.model('User', UserSchema),
createUser: function (newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, null, null, function (err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);

    });

}
};
```